# How to get location from different sources in iOS?

Tags: ios, gps, geolocation, core-location

I am new to iOS and Objective C programming. I am trying to build Core Location Framework to get location. In Android, we can get location from different providers, like GPS,network,WiFi and fused.

Now, in iOS, I can get location by specifying only accuracy,

```
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;        
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

But, how I make sure, that location is coming from GPS, or Network or any other provider?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS you need not worry about location provider. Based on the accuracy you are setting, iOS framework will itself take decision and will push the location. You can not specify location provider in iOS.